# Bootstrap keep certain <li> outside of the collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the default bootstrap 3 navbar with collapse but I'm wondering if

Is it possible to keep certain items in the nav while it's collapsed? (see my screenshot for an example), without using Javascript.

#### How it is now, default

[image]

#### Desired

[image]

Comment: There can be some possibilities but please share your code with us so that we might offer you some suggestions if there are any.

Comment: Please show the relevant code ("*[mcve]*" HTML, CSS and JavaScript) to accompany the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           </head>
           <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="nav-container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FUNducation</a>
      <button href="" class="btn navbar-btn pull-right" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    
      <!--<a href="" ><button class="btn navbar-btn" id="stud">Studier demo</button></a>-->
      <a href="" ><button class="btn  navbar-btn" id="help">CHEERS</button></a>
      <!--<li class="diff"><a class="nav_list" href="testlogin.php">--><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>--> <!--Sign Up</a></li>-->
      <a href="" ><button class="btn  navbar-btn" id="friend">LOG-IN</button></a>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Add the compose button inside `<div class="navbar-header">` . That's it.

As suggested by Notflip This is the approach to solve the horizontal align problem. We both think this would help future visitors.

[Check out this fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/nomis/n9KtL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/nomis/n9KtL/1/)

Cheers!

Comment: With the `.pull-right` class to keep it aligned at the right.

Comment: CHECK THE SNIPPET

Comment: Let me try! Thanks for this! you're fast

Comment: The only issue is that following: http://imgur.com/a/ZBFnB it's not getting behind the others. because they are in a sepeare nav-right.

Comment: USE <BUTTON href="" class="btn navbar-btn pull-right" id="signup">Sign Up</BUTTON> instead of < li> if that's what you are using check the snippet it is aligned

Comment: Well I mean the position horizontal is off. It should be all the way on the right, but i'm guessing that's not possible? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Aha! These guys fixed it using this: http://jsfiddle.net/nomis/n9KtL/1/

Comment: Glad that it got soled!

Comment: Could you maybe add the fiddle to your answer for future visitors? :)

Comment: Added the fiddle to the answer done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, if you keep "Compose" button  in between nav "container" class and outside "navbar-collapse collapse" class.

For more details, please share the code.

Comment: Thanks! the issue is in the normal 'desktop' view it's in the wrong place, should I make a duplicate and hide it? But that seems like bad practice

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with only CSS.

You will have to definitely go with JavaScript for it.

Create a element whose default style is **display:none;** and when the nav is collapsed, make the style of that element **display: block;**

Comment: For the solution you mentioned you don't need to use javascript. There is someting called `@media` query. See more: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp. This user simply need to put the button out of the scope instead of the navbar's list.